# Using nested Read Uncommitted in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

In a query on a DB2 v10 for z/os, I need to pull data from live production lines, so I can't have any lock put on them. Accuracy in this situation is second to locking up data, as locking data would be very bad for production. My goal is to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO newTable 
SELECT a, b, c  
FROM (SELECT d, e, f 
      FROM tableB b
      FOR FETCH ONLY WITH UR)
```

I've tried all that I can think of doing, but it seems like whenever i put code inside of the FROM statement, it gives me an error on the "FOR FETCH ONLY WITH UR" even though it hasn't before when the same code is in other places. The error I get when I put "FOR FETCH ONLY WITH UR' or even just "WITH UR" is usually SQLCODE -199 "ILLEGAL USE OF FOR/WITH....."

I've also tried doing something like this:

```
INSERT INTO newTable
WITH tableA AS (
      SELECT d, e, f 
      FROM tableB b
      FOR FETCH ONLY WITH UR
      )
SELECT a, b, c
FROM tableA
```

but I so far haven't found a way to specify WITH UR or to not lock data in tableB, while at the same time being able to use it for processing and putting it into newTable. What am I doing wrong and is it even possible to do what I want to do?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why are using a common table expression or inner select when you can just get the data   insert into newTable select a,b,c from tableA

Comment: The data from tableA is being manipulated using a number of joins and unions so I can't directly grab things from it. That being said, even if I did then I still couldn't not have a lock on that table while inserting could I?

Comment: If your doing a number of joins and unions you should show them to us so we can better help.